# How do I use HMSET with node promisify

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, node-promisify

I am using node (TypeScript) and node-redis library. Since I use TypeScript, I also imported @types/redis.

In addition, I read this article on how to promisify redis methods for TypeScript usage: https://flaviocopes.com/node-promisify/

My problem is that is that it works for some redis methods (like GET, SET, etc) but it does not work with e.g. HSET or HGETALL.

If I look into type suggestions, I see the critical methods are actually not methods at all, but rather properties (hset, HSET):

[image]

Why is this so?  How can I access those needed methods?

I guess I am doing something obvious wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the [source code of the typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redis/index.d.ts) and it seems that e.g. `get` is defined as a function:

```
get(key: string, cb?: Callback<string | null>): R;
```

whereas `hset` is defined as:

```
hset: OverloadedSetCommand<string, number, R>;
```

Altough `OverloadedSetCommand` is defined as

```
export interface OverloadedCommand<T, U, R> {
    (arg1: T, arg2: T, arg3: T, arg4: T, arg5: T, arg6: T, cb?: Callback<U>): R;
    (arg1: T, arg2: T, arg3: T, arg4: T, arg5: T, cb?: Callback<U>): R;
    (arg1: T, arg2: T, arg3: T, arg4: T, cb?: Callback<U>): R;
    (arg1: T, arg2: T, arg3: T, cb?: Callback<U>): R;
    (arg1: T, arg2: T | T[], cb?: Callback<U>): R;
    (arg1: T | T[], cb?: Callback<U>): R;
    (...args: Array<T | Callback<U>>): R;
}
```

it seems that it's interpreted as a property (the same happens in Webstorm not only in vscode btw).

If I manually override the definition as:

```
hset(hash: string, field: string, value:any): R;
```

the code completion shows a function as expected.

Maybe you can raise an issue on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped but for now I guess you have to just go with it.